# How do I use "like" vs "likes" in speech and sentences?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

I'm a bit confused with the usage of this word. Sometimes I see it with an 's' and other times there isn't one.

How do I use this word properly in a sentence both oral and written?

eg.

> Henry '**likes**' ice-cream.

or

> He would '**like**' some ice-cream and some chocolate cake.

Comment: In your second sentence, the verb **like** is connected to the modal verb **would** and because of this the verb **like** cannot have the first-person-singular inflection **s**

Comment: @CopperKettle sorry I'm more confused what do you mean by 'cannot be infected'?

Comment: **[inflected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection#Examples_in_English)**, not *infected*. (0: You cannot change the form of the verb if it comes after **[a modal verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs)**.

Comment: You're welcome! I made a mistake - it's a *third-person* inflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the gist of it in your examples. Following a noun, 'like' is appropriate, but when following a verb, 'likes' is the proper term.

Examples:

> **1** Cats like milk.
>   **2** My cat should like going to the beach.

Comment: in my case I don't have a verb, if I recall from my English class, a verb is a 'doing word' or 'action'? So liking something is an considered an action? pardon my stupidity, this language can be confusing.

Comment: Yes, 'like' is a 'doing' word, it is an action. Verbs encompass more than physical actions. When using the phrase 'would like' the whole thing is considered the verb.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I took the words literally when they say 'action' or 'doing word'. I didn't think emotions and feelings were also part of verbs. I thought it was limited to physically action, as in run, jump and talking etc.

Comment: @TheLazyChap: Often you can ask "What am I doing?" If you can answer with the *-ing* form, it's a verb: *I'm liking*, *I'm thinking*, *I'm feeling*. But it's not always that easy. For *will*, it's okay to say *I'm willing*. But for the word *can*, you'd have to say, *I'm being able to*, because *canning* means putting things in cans. Note that in the form, *I'm [verb]ing*, the word *am* is a part of the verb form (*I am [verb]ing*), and is sometimes called a helping verb or an auxiliary verb.

Comment: @RJH Wow, damn you're giving more terms to think about auxiliary thats a first for me. Thanks, I can see why I was struggled a lot with grammar and English in general. Thank you. Yeah I always though 'like' is more of a feeling than an action, you either like it or you don't. You're not really 'doing', maybe my view is a bit shallow on verbs.

Comment: @TheLazyChap English tends to express attributes of the subject as verbs instead of adjectives. These are called *stative verbs* and can express physical and abstract attributes of the subject, including feelings . For example, in many languages to say "I like ice-cream", you would say the equivalent of "to me, ice-cream is pleasing".  Here is a list of stative verbs: http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/stative-verbs.html

Answer (score 1):

When you use a phrase with third person singular and you have a conditional or two verbs like (He must do, He can do, He would like, He would love etc.), rules say:

> The second verb after any auxiliary verb is always in the infinitive form.

You can to check on [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/would-like)  and [eslcafe.](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/verb_forms_and_tenses02.html)

### Examples

Here are some examples

> He can do it.
>
> She must go to London.
>
> It must go out.